# Invalid data source names - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I've had this code running for PDO connection to my database.
Since last couple of hours, I'm getting a weird error called "**invalid data source name**".

I've searched quite a bit but I'm getting no solutions for it. What might be the reason?

Connection Code

```
<?php
$connectionString = 'mysqlhost=127.0.0.1;dbname=cdm';
try
{
$conn = new PDO($connectionString, 'root', 'PASS1234');
$conn->setAttribute(PDOATTR_ERRMODE, PDOERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

var_dump($conn);
?>
```

**Output**

```
invalid data source nameNULL
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your entire code is totally wrong.

first fix :

`$connectionString = 'mysqlhost=127.0.0.1;dbname=cdm';` to `$connectionString = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=dgsa';`

Then change the following :

`$conn->setAttribute(PDOATTR_ERRMODE, PDOERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

To :

`$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Full correct code :

```
<?php
$connectionString = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=dgsa';
try
{
$conn = new PDO($connectionString, 'root', 'PASS1234');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

var_dump($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I used find and replace on all open files replace ":" with something else, which most probably caused this.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to change the variable to this :

```
$connectionString = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=cdm';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a typo

`$connectionString = 'mysqlhost=127.0.0.1;dbname=cdm';`

should be

`$connectionString = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=cdm';` ( with : )